# What happens when writing to aux file on Windows?

Tags: java, windows

I have the following code:

```
public class MyTest {
  public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    java.io.File f = new java.io.File("aux.txt");
    f.createNewFile();
    java.io.FileWriter fw = new java.io.FileWriter(f);          
    fw.write("Hello");
    fw.flush();
    fw.close();
  }
}
```

The code runs and does not throw any exception. Except: the file aux.txt is not there. I found that `f.createNewFile()` return false, [because the aux file is not allowed to be created on windows](https://blog.onetechnical.com/2006/11/16/forbidden-file-and-folder-names-on-windows/). Ok, I can live with that.

But, my confusion is this: If the `FileWriter` did not throw any exception, where did it write to?

Comment: It attempts to write to the AUX device, usually COM1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#file_and_directory_names)

> Do not use the following reserved names for the name of a file:
>   CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. Also avoid these names followed immediately by an extension; for example, NUL.txt is not recommended.

`false` returned means, that the file already exists. According to [this blog](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/create-restricted-files-folders-con-aux-nul-click-windows) writing to `AUX` on `Windows` causes writing to Auxiliary device, usually a serial port.

In addition, try writing to a file called `CON`. It should appear in console.

Comment: Hm...neither `CON` nor any of the variants such as `con.txt` did write to console for me...

Comment: Did you try launching the application from the console or from IDE? It works that way in many technologies.

Comment: You are right! When running from console using ant, it did not write it. When I just run it using `java MyTest`, it did!